# how to pass a php variabe to yiibooster modal window via link

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-booster

I want to pass a php variable to modal window , what i am doing is opening a modal window using this link , but i want to pass a variable to this link and get same variable in modal window , i try to to do this to append a text in some div but it return html that i am unable to get in query

```
 echo CHtml::link(
                                'Set Recipe', '', array(
                            'class' => 'testclass',
                            'id' => $finalDate,
                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                            'data-target' => '#myModal',
                            'fahadVar' => $finalDate
                        ));
```

and when i click this button i got modal window how to get variable set in button 
Here is simple modal code of yiibooster

```
     <div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body...</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<?php $this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
array(
'type' => 'primary',
'label' => 'Save changes',
'url' => '#',
'htmlOptions' => array('data-dismiss' => 'modal'),
)
); ?>
<?php $this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
array(
'label' => 'Close',
'url' => '#',
'htmlOptions' => array('data-dismiss' => 'modal'),
)
); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Widget.

Note: I copied below from another post. It works like charm.

First Create a new widget. Let say the name is CategoryWidget. Put this widget under components directory protected/components.

```
class CategoryWidget extends CWidget {

    public function run() {
        $models = Category::model()->findAll();

        $this->render('category', array(
            'models'=>$models   
        ));
    }
}
```

Then create a view for this widget. The file name is category.php. Put it under protected/components/views
category.php

```
<?php if($models != null): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($models as $model): ?>
    <li><?php echo $model->name; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then call this widget from your main layout. 
main.php
// your code ...

```
<?php $this->widget('CategoryWidget') ?>
```